# WPF Assigning control Properties using reflection in c sharp

Tags: wpf, reflection, late-binding

I am trying to create an application that creates objects from data that is read from an XML file.

Using reflection I have managed to create the objects I need and assign some of the properties like primitive types and ENUM types.

For primitive types where property is a Dictionary entry with the Property name to change and the value to set

```
 type.GetProperty((string)property.Key).SetValue(control, Convert.ChangeType((string)property.Value, propertyType, null), null);
```

and for ENUM types

```
object desiredPropertyValue = Enum.Parse(propertyType, (string)property.Value);
                    propertyInfo.SetValue(control, desiredPropertyValue, null);
```

The problem I have is that I can't seem to find a way to set other types of properties like Fontweight, fontfamily, Margin and many others I think these are of type structure, any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You can use the associated type converters to convert the objects to/from a string. For example, for FontWeight you can use the [FontWeightConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.fontweightconverter.aspx) like so:

```
object value = new FontWeightConverter().ConvertFromString((string)property.Value)
```

Likewise, you can use ConvertToString to convert to a string for saving in your dictionary.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but with this method I still need to have prior knowledge that fontWeight is the attribute I want changed and have to   create a fontweight converter.