# WPF Reflection, Late Binding

Tags: wpf, reflection

I am trying to set properties on WPF controls (height, width, fontweight, margin and many others) from data that is read through an XML file. I am not going to know what properties are going to be set beforehand. I was wondering if anyone knows a way to do this through reflection?

At the moment I have managed to assign all of the primitive types and enum types using reflection but I am having a little bit of trouble with properties like `FontWeight`, `Margin`, `Background` and many others that require other objects in setting the property for instance: To set a `FontWeight` property of a button you have to do it like this.

```
button.FontWeight = Fontweights.Bold;
```

or a Margin

```
button.Margin = new Thickness(10, 10, 10, 10);
```

As there are a possible 150 + properties that could be set on the controls in WPF I just wanted to avoid this sort of code.

```
public void setProperties(String propertyName, string PropertyValue
{

     if(propertyName = "Margin")
     {
         Set the margin.....
     }
     else if (propertyName = "FontWeight")
     {
         set the FontWeight....
     }
}
```

and so on for each possible property that can be set on WPF controls.

Comment: How is this different than your other [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6073677/wpf-assigning-control-properties-using-reflection-in-c-sharp/6074928#comment-7063772)?

Answer (score 1):

Behind the scenes, XAML uses `TypeConverter`s to convert from string to the specified type. You can use them yourself, since each of the types you mentioned has a default `TypeConverter` specified using the [`TypeConverterAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.typeconverterattribute.aspx). You can use it like this (or alternatively, make the method generic):

```
object Convert(Type targetType, string value)
{
    var converter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(targetType);
    return converter.ConvertFromString(value);
}
```

Then each of the following works as expected:

```
Convert(typeof(Thickness), "0 5 0 0")
Convert(typeof(FontWeight), "Bold")
Convert(typeof(Brush), "Red")
```

Answer (score 1):

It's actually really simple. You read your string values into properties on a ViewModel, set that view model to your DataContext, and in xaml bind up your properties. [Binding uses TypeConverters automaticall](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx#creating_a_binding)y.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
typeof(Button).GetProperty("FontWeight").SetValue(button1,GetFontWeight("Bold"), null);
```

EDIT:

You can have a mapping function that convert string to property value

```
FontWeight GetFontWeight(string value)
{

   swithc(value)
   {
     case "Bold" : return FontWeights.Bold; break;
     ...
   }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer but with your code I still have to know that it is the FontWeight property that I am going to set to pass a FontWeights.Bold object into the setValue method.